# android java --key is same but containsKey return false

Tags: java, android, containskey

I have to put values in LinkedHashMap.
(because, I want sorting and determinig if there are values already)

I thought containsKey return true if String values are same like **temp** and **temp2**.
However, **testMap.put(temp2,8);** is running.

I don't know why.
If that is not correct answer, How can I store or access values in fast way??

```java
 public class TestClass{
        public String one;
        public String two;
        TestClass(String one, String two){
            this.one=one;
            this.two=two;
        }
    }
    public void testPersonWord(){
        LinkedHashMap<TestClass, Integer> testMap= new LinkedHashMap<>();
        TestClass temp= new TestClass("hdy","hello");
        testMap.put(temp,3);
        TestClass temp2= new TestClass("hdy","hello");
        if(testMap.containsKey(temp2)){
            testMap.replace(temp2,5);
        }else{
            testMap.put(temp2,8);
        }
    }
```

Comment: temp and temp2 have different hashcode, that's why it's jumping to else statement. What you can do is create a toString() in TestClass, and then try to equate it, I guess that will work.

Comment: To best approach Use a HashMap whose keys are the names or integer value and whose values are the TestClass. And in your code, as you mentioned it's going to an else statement because first, you put temp2 in testMap before comparing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is `containKey` method. The `hashCode` is used for comparing so definitely the hashCode of two object is difference so it can not be equal.
You can consider to use primitive key or use TestClass.getOne() to compare String.

```
/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this map contains a mapping for the
 * specified key.
 *
 * @param   key   The key whose presence in this map is to be tested
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this map contains a mapping for the specified
 * key.
 */
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getNode(hash(key), key) != null;
}
```

Hope this helps !